# what is happening inside the loop and how the output is like this for let variable?

Tags: javascript, scope, var, let

```js
let printNumTwo;
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i;
    };
  }
}
console.log(printNumTwo());
```

output : 2

How is this output become 2; explain what is happening inside the loop and scope of let.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply because the only wait for the `printNumTwo` variable to hold a function which return the value of `i` **(i==2)** is only when the `i` counter is equal to `2` otherwise nothing is executed. for all other value of counter `i` the `printNumTwo` will not be touched. That's the main reason.

Answer (score 1):

Well basically it is looping and *i* is how many times its looped in simple words. So in your case, *i* starts at 0 and goes to 3, meaning it will loop 3 times. And you made an if statement inside which is:

```
if (i === 2) {//do stuff}
```

It basically just checked that if *i* is 2 - or that its the second loop, it will run. So when it was the second loop, it console logged *2* by the code you wrote:

```
printNumTwo = function() {
  return i;
};
```

And then *printNumTwo* was console logged (printNumTwo was *i*, or, 2).
I hope that made sense.

Answer (score 0):

Because this code return `i` when its equal to `2` and by calling the `printNumTwo()` function, it also returns `2` because the code stopped the loop by returning it .

Answer (score 0):

Because your using a for loop with a iterator variable that increments its value and stops until its stopping condition is met. Your global scoped variable has a value of the returned function which returns the iterators value.